# How to find the line of the crash?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have some beginner trouble using xCode. Each time the app crash I find it hard to find the problem as I don't understand the log currently I seem to have a problem with a Array. I think it is a Array of which I deleted the class where it was in.

I would like to know how I should read this log :

```
2014-05-02 10:49:32.808 myCompany[2793:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f21e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015718e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017a4abc -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x017a4760 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   UIKit                               0x00794a4b PushNextClassForSettingIMP + 383
    5   UIKit                               0x00794838 __workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget_block_invoke + 29
    6   UIKit                               0x00284413 +[UIView _performCustomizableAppearanceModifications:] + 26
    7   UIKit                               0x00794810 workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget + 940
    8   UIKit                               0x0078ee71 +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:] + 3779
    9   UIKit                               0x0078f633 +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:] + 55
    10  UIKit                               0x0029b5a3 -[UIView(Internal) _applyAppearanceInvocations] + 270
    11  UIKit                               0x0029c002 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 65
    12  UIKit                               0x0029bf8f -[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 204
    13  UIKit                               0x0029bebe -[UIView(Internal) _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 52
    14  UIKit                               0x003f44b7 -[UILabel(_UIAccessibilityButtonShapesSupportInternal) _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 73
    15  UIKit                               0x004ed776 -[UITabBarButtonLabel _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 73
    16  UIKit                               0x0029be82 -[UIView(Internal) _didChangeFromIdiomOnScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 172
    17  UIKit                               0x0029b466 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1624
    18  UIKit                               0x0029b109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    19  UIKit                               0x00334458 -[UIControl _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 65
    20  UIKit                               0x0029b109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    21  UIKit                               0x004fad59 -[UITabBar(UITabBarPrivate) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 65
    22  UIKit                               0x0029b109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    23  UIKit                               0x0029296f __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 158
    24  UIKit                               0x002927fb -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 260
    25  UIKit                               0x0029ddd4 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1875
    26  UIKit                               0x00290dba -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    27  UIKit                               0x00270406 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 481
    28  UIKit                               0x002705ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    29  UIKit                               0x0027086b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    30  UIKit                               0x0027b3c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    31  UIKit                               0x0022bbc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
    32  UIKit                               0x00230667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    33  UIKit                               0x00244f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    34  UIKit                               0x00245555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    35  UIKit                               0x00232250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x037e7f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x037e7a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0176dca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0176d9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0179868c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x017979d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x017977eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    43  UIKit                               0x0022fd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    44  UIKit                               0x00231f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    45  myCompany                                 0x000043fd main + 141
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e39701 start + 1
)
```

EDIT :

```
this caused the problem :

UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.PNG"]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setImage:tabBackground];
```

Still I don't understand why it can't just display the line of error like android. I found this by comment lining

Comment: See this link - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1.

Comment: add expection break point

Comment: debug line by line..:)

Comment: I got the all exception breakpoint it just does nothing

Comment: when exception comes it will stop.

Comment: Yes I know I have tried it but it doesn't stop in all situations as this is one it just doesn't stop anywhere

Comment: Try to put NSLog after your each array insertion. Example: insertObject:atIndex:]; After that add NSLog and check.

Comment: The whole point of my question is that I find it annoying that I can't find the line of code without doing things like NSLog or commentlining  //

Comment: why are you using `resizableImageWithCapInsets` whith zeroinsets? It doesn't make sense

Comment: I just copy pasted that for the syntax, but that is not the problem I would just like to know how I can find the problem line as the all exception break point doesn't seem to work that well

Comment: Realize that `appearance` is a singleton. It involved lazily so you never know when the incorrect appearance attributes will crash your app.

Comment: Dude, you helped me solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you must follow up this tutorial, clearly mentioning about this

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

According to your log details,

1. You are trying to create array with nil objects.
2. Trying to insert nil object to array

both above will crash the app.

**Enable zombies**

Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics-> Click Enable Zombie Objects

You forgot to add nil at last index in array creation.

like this

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2"];
```

But it should be

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",nil];
```

But If you are using NSMutableArray and add objects,then u should valid to nil condition like below.

```
       if (myObjectToBeAddedToArray!=nil) {

        [arrayMutable addObject:myObjectToBeAddedToArray];

       }
```